# Reactive Extensions and IDisposable management

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, system.reactive

I'm trying to use `Async` versions of `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure`, but I'm having hard time figuring out how to do session management with Reactive Extensions.

Here's some background:

- One can create a CIM session using [`CimSession.CreateAsync`](https://github.com/PowerShell/MMI/blob/cf32fc695b32c2eae848b693395c09222fe1d2ae/src/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure/CimSession.cs#L177-L219), which returns `IObservable`
- `CimSession.CreateAsync` returns a [`CimAsyncResult<T>`](https://github.com/PowerShell/MMI/blob/b35df8fcf766127221aaa02c474540aa95249722/src/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure/Generic/CimAsyncResult.cs), which wraps [`CimAsyncDelegatedObservable<T>`](https://github.com/PowerShell/MMI/blob/b35df8fcf766127221aaa02c474540aa95249722/src/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure/Internal/Operations/CimAsyncDelegatedObservable.cs)
- `CimAsyncDelegatedObservable<T>` [does not dispose `CimSession`](https://github.com/PowerShell/MMI/blob/b35df8fcf766127221aaa02c474540aa95249722/src/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure/Internal/Operations/CimAsyncDelegatedObservable.cs#L43) at any point, and thus one must manually dispose `CimSession` when it is not needed anymore.
- After getting a handle to `CimSession`, I'm trying to run a WQL query using [`QueryInstancesAsync`](https://github.com/PowerShell/MMI/blob/cf32fc695b32c2eae848b693395c09222fe1d2ae/src/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure/CimSession.cs#L912-L936), for example `session.QueryInstancesAsync(@"root\cimv2", "WQL", "SELECT Username FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")`

If `CimSession` returned `Task`s instead of `Observable`s, the code would be pretty straightforward:

```cs
using var session = CimSession.CreateAsync(".");
var results = session.QueryInstancesAsync(@"root\cimv2", "WQL", "SELECT Username FROM Win32_ComputerSystem");
```

But as the `Async` methods are implemented using `Observable`s, I'm not sure how to translate this to idiomatic usage of `Observable`s. Sure I could translate my methods to `Task`s using `System.Reactive.Linq.Observable.ForEachAsync`, but I'd like to learn how to use Observables properly.

To sum it up, my questions would be:

- Bind lifetime of a `CimSession` to `Observable`
- How to make sure `CimSession` gets disposed, if there are no subscribers? Should I force at least one subscriber, but having factory method?
- How to dispose `CimSession` observable when results for `QueryInstancesAsync` arrive?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a whacky interface, but give this a go and let me know if it works:

```
IObservable<string> query =
    from session in CimSession.CreateAsync(".")
    from x in Observable.Using(
        () => session,
        s => s.QueryInstancesAsync(@"root\cimv2", "WQL", "SELECT Username FROM Win32_ComputerSystem"))
    from y in Observable.Using(
        () => x,
        z => Observable.Return(z.GetCimSessionComputerName()))
    select y;
```

---

If that works, I'd suggest wrapping it in a separate class:

```
public static class CimSessionEx
{
    public static IObservable<T> CreateObservable<T>(string computerName, string namespaceName, string queryDialect, string queryExpression, Func<CimInstance, IObservable<T>> factory) =>
        from session in CimSession.CreateAsync(computerName)
        from instance in Observable.Using(() => session, s => s.QueryInstancesAsync(namespaceName, queryDialect, queryExpression))
        from y in Observable.Using(() => instance, factory)
        select y;
}
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
IObservable<string> query =
    CimSessionEx.CreateObservable(
        ".",
        @"root\cimv2",
        "WQL",
        "SELECT Username FROM Win32_ComputerSystem",
        i => Observable.Return(i.GetCimSessionComputerName()));
```